# Fast TIFF image conversion to show in web-client

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, image-processing, tiff

For preview of scanned TIFF-document currently I use the following:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(@"document.tif");
var ms = new MemoryStream();

bmp.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Png);

var bmpBytes = ms.GetBuffer();
bmp.Dispose();
ms.Close();

return new FileStreamResult(new MemoryStream(bmpBytes), "image/png");
```

Is there any way to speed up the conversion? Using something else than standard Image.Save() method?

I've found unsafe class which locks and unlocks bitmapData between pixel manipulation [here](http://www.vcskicks.com/fast-image-processing.php), but I'm not sure that it's suitable for my task (because I need only to transform from one format to another). However my profiler shows about 30ms win (before 116 ms, after 83 ms)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FreeImage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/) is a great image manipulation library, there are C# wrappers for it. You can find the [FreeImage .NET documentation](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/fnet/Index.html) too.

Quite mature so several elements of it are highly optimised.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check it out in near future to compare with current solution via Atalasoft library.

Comment: According to documentation it is what I want! Thanks again! ))

Answer (score 1):

I think i found it! :) [Atalasoft dotImage](http://atalasoft.com) (free edition) boost image showing to about 35ms...

Answer (score 0):

I'm using an external tool for the conversion: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php

It's a lot faster.

**Update**

Do something like this:

```
var sourceFile = "C:\\yourscanned.tiff";
var destFile = Path.GetTempPath() + "\\yourpng.tmp";
var process = Process.Start("C:\path\to\imagick\convert.exe", sourceFile + " " + destFile);
process.WaitForExit();

FileStream myStream = new FileStream(destFile);
//woho, do what you want.

File.Delete(destFile);
```

Comment: I've tried ImageMagick.NET wrapper. It seems that it could solve my issue but API is rather uncomfortably and poorly documented. Didn't try external imagemagick yet because I prefer .NET pure solutions, but I'll keep in mind your suggestion (if don't find any other way). Thanks!

Comment: Do you use imagemagick for a task similar to mine? I mean for sending generated png (or jpeg) to client-side without saving it to disk? If so, would you please provide me brief sample?

Comment: I'm using imagick to convert pdf to tiff. I'm not using the .Net wrapper since it just made things harder :) Look after examples for the tool instead. You cannot do it without saving the file to disk (at least not with imagick), just create a temp file for the process and delete it when done)